# How do I find a substring in a command line?

Tags: text-processing, scripting, search

I have a few files that contains a similar entry like as follows:

```
{"result":[]}
{"result":[{"alternative":[{"transcript":"I win","confidence":0.87958056},{"transcript":"when"},{"transcript":"Schwinn"},{"transcript":"Gwen"},{"transcript":"I went"}],"final":true}],"result_index":0}
```

Basically there's a string that has a "confidence" associated with it. This string always appears before the string "confidence". In this case, the target string is "I win". Using command line linux tools, how would I parse this file to get the target string?

Answer (score 1):

It's JSON, and linux tools are not very good for working with JSON. And your conditions are not very clear... But this perl one-liner produces from your example string "I win"

```
perl -0777 -nE 's/.*"(.+?)","confidence".*/$1/s; say'
```

Answer (score 1):

The "simple" answer is to use `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/.*\("[^"]*"\),"confidence".*/\1/p' filename
```

This will print `"I win"`. 
To exclude the quotes (and get just `I win` as the output),
move the first two double quotes in the command outside of the parentheses:

```
sed -n 's/.*"\([^"]*\)","confidence".*/\1/p' filename
```

The better answer is to get a tool that's designed to parse JSON data.